# Strange bootstrap behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Bootstrap 3`. I have noticed a strange behavior that when I use class `.col-md-6` on a `<div>`, it occupies half the area as it should be, but when I use class `.col-md-4` on the same `<div>`, it occupies the whole row.

Below are the attached images.

1) Image with `.col-md-6`:
[image: image with col-md-6]

2) Image with `.col-md-4`:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: tried to add `form-control`?

Comment: No. But what difference it will make? Bootstrap classes should work on divs as defined.

Comment: Why are you mixing bootstraps grid system with a table for this... just use the grid?

Comment: I'll try with that one too. But I don't think its due to the use of table. I'll try without tables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.col-xs-4`. I suspect it's due to the breakpoints since they're stacking....

Comment: I need to modify it a little bit. Business constraint. I'll post it in sometime.

Comment: Are you sure you have included Boostrap CSS into your project? It is not in the codepen and you have manually created the .col-md-6 CSS.... ?

Comment: I don't think there is a manually created class .col-md-6. It is somehow splitting the row in two parts. But anything other than .col-md-6 is not working.

Comment: There is no such custom defined class.

Comment: @Waquar In your Codepen, Twitter Bootstrap CSS is NOT included, it's not loaded, you haven't added it. Further more, a manually created `.col-md-6` class IS there. Line 14 - 17. `.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}`